# Radio buttons in Template-Driven Forms

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular7, ngfor

Every time the page loads the last radio button is always checked. I know it has something to do with Id but I cannot figure out how to solve it.

**countryArray**

```js
countryA = [{name : "Finland"}, {name : "china"},{name :  "USA"}]
```

**test.html**

```html
            <form #filterForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="addFilter(filterForm)" autocomplete="off">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-12" style="border: 1px solid red">
                        <div *ngFor="let x of country">
                            <label for="{{x.name}}"> {{x.name}} </label>
                            <input type="radio" id="{{x.name}}" value="{{x.name}}" name="countries" [(ngModel)]='x.name' >
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- <div class="col-12" style="border: 1px solid red">b</div>
                    <div class="col-12" style="border: 1px solid red">c</div>
                    <div class="col-12" style="border: 1px solid red">D</div> -->
                </div>
            </form>
            hh : {{filterForm.value | json}}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should add a selected property to each country to use as ngModel for value of radio button:

in constructor:

```
this.country = this.country.map(item =>({ name: item.name , selected : false }));
```

in html:

```
<div class="col-12" style="border: 1px solid red">
    <div *ngFor="let x of country; index as i">
        <label for="{{x.name}}"> {{x.name}} </label>
        <input type="radio" id="{{x.name}}" value="{{x.name}}" name="countries" [(ngModel)]="country[i].selected">
    </div>
</div>
```

check [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-radio-buttons-demo-template-driven-form-xw3unw).

Comment: @menime you're welcome, please accept the answer if it was helpful.

Comment: done :) Would you, please, help me with [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59337919/post-data-from-two-forms-as-one-object-in-angular/59338075#59338075)

Answer (score 0):

You are applying `ngModel` to 'x.name' and it is a reason why it is checked. You can create a variable `selectedRadio` and assign value of radio button:

```
<div *ngFor="let x of country">
    <label for="{{x.name}}"> {{x.name}} </label>
    <input type="radio" 
        id="{{x.name}}" 
        value="{{x.name}}"
        [(ngModel)] ="selectedRadio"
        name="countries">
</div>
<p> {{ selectedRadio | json }} </p>
```

TypeScript:

```
selectedRadio: any;
```

A stackblitz [example can be seen here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6dgzw7?file=src/app/app.component.html).

Comment: I was actually doing this when I started making this form but I guess made a mistake somewhere else as it was not working for me. But anyways, Thanks for making time for my issue

Comment: @MenimE [what should I do when someone answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) please, mark Fateme Fazli mark as an answer because she was earlier than me.