# Post Data from two forms as one Object in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, forms, angular-services

This is my first project on Angular and I have done as much as I could and I will try to finish it myself but I feel like that I require help.

A brief description of the project : 
I have a class **mod.ts**

```
export interface Mod {
    id : number ,
    name? : string,
    clauseList? : Clause
    country? : string;
    company? : string;
    process? : string;
}

export interface Clause {
    cName? : string,
    cid? : number,
    // pc : number,
    parentC?  :number,
    id? : number,
    text? : Text
}


export interface Text {
    txt? : string,
    tid? : number
}
```

This is the structure of form data that a user will send to the backend and the values will come from two different forms. 
I have named the forms as clauseForm and filterForm. The filterform is a collection of radio buttons from 4 different arrays and the clauseForm is 3 input fields.

I have shared a  [stackblitz demo here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mbix8n)

here is the flow, The user selects the values from the radio buttons and saves them as an object(to use them later), then the user clicks on the edit form and fills in the fields. once the user clicks on add in this form, we should see a div with displaying the text entered in the "txt" field of the form and, simultaneously, all the data should be pushed into finalPostArray from which it can be sent to the server. This is how I am planning to do it, idk if there is an alternative. 
I cannot figure out how to use the two forms to send the data to the server as one object. Please help or let me know if you need more clarification.

**Stackblitz Updated. Please refer to the README.txt**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to merge form data from both objects you can do:

```
finalData = {};

saveClause(form: NgForm) {
   this.show1 = true;
   Object.assign(this.finalData, form.value);
}

addFilter(filter: NgForm) {
   Object.assign(this.finalData, filter.value);
   filter.reset();
}
```

Now depending on your use case you can decide when to *post* this data to the backend.

---

EDIT:

Since you want to merge into a single object use:

```
finalPostArray = [];
mergedObj = {};

saveClause(form: NgForm) {
   ... 
   Object.assign(this.mergedObj, form.value);
   this.finalPostArray.push(this.mergedObj);
   ... 
}

addFilter(filter: NgForm) {
   Object.assign(this.mergedObj, filter.value);
   filter.reset();
}
```

[Working stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ujdfes)

Comment: thanks man, I have updated the demo and I am confused with the POST request. Would you please take a look

Comment: When does the POST happen? Also, what doesn't work with the it? ++If you you are trying to save everything in an array then you need to push it to the array i.e  `this.finalPostArray.push(filter.value);`

Comment: I don't know why I am getting this on Stackblitz only but when I press "save" on my local machine, I can see the Array populate with form values but on Stackblitz the array does not gets populated with the values.

Comment: I've forked your stackblitz and made the changes I was talking about in [my earlier comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59337919/post-data-from-two-forms-as-one-object-in-angular/59338062#comment104880512_59338062). Here's the [stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ujdfes).

Comment: The finalPostArray has two objects inside, I need a single object with nested objects inside of it. I have the same code on Stackblitz and my local machine, I don't understand why it's not working here. The Array looks like this on my local machine [Img](https://imgur.com/zZEgaet)

Comment: I've made edits as per your latest comment. Check out the same stackblitz link again.

Comment: This is "I HOPE" the last issue I am facing, I called a service method in .ts to save the data into a dummy array on service.ts i.e in finalData. On my local machine, I can add the data and the console shows the new object has been added but the values from the addFilter method are not added (as there is no save method called) to the array and only the values in clauseList are added. I have updated the [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mtyurw) with the new methods in service and .ts and sharing [Image](https://imgur.com/qBWR6ld)

Comment: Seems like another issue. Could you create another question for that? (As this one deals with only merging two objects into one)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this create a `finalData` array where you can accumulate the data you receive from your form1 and form2 and when user finally click on save button you can send data of `finalData`.

```
  form1Data = [];
  form2Data = [];
  finalData = [];

  saveClause(form  :NgForm){
    console.log("Form Values",form.value);
    this.form1Data = form.value;
    this.show1 = true
  }

  addFilter(filter : NgForm){
    console.log("FilterForm Value",filter.value)
    this.form2Data = filter.value;
    this.finalData.push({
      ...this.form1Data,
      ...this.form2Data
    });

    console.log(this.finalData);

    filter.reset()
  }
```

**working demo** : [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xyiwrk)

**Note** : see console for final result.